# ValueError: Tensor is not an element of this graph, when hosting a model in Sagemaker with Gunicorn and Flask and Keras

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I created a time series predictor with Keras and  Dockerized the model with with Flash and Gunicorn as per AWS docs. I am loading the serialized model with this code.

```
@classmethod
def get_model(cls):
    if cls.model == None:
        cls.model = load_model('/opt/ml/bitcoin_model.h5')
    return cls.model
```

Then I used the predict method to produce the results , the dockerized container is working perfectly in the local environment , but when I try to host the model in sagemaker it produces this error.

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

So how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by calling _make_predict_function() method in the model load phase.

```
@classmethod
def get_model(cls):
    if cls.model == None:
        cls.model = load_model('/opt/ml/bitcoin_model.h5')
        cls.model._make_predict_function()
    return cls.model
```

Bug Reference : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462